# if(data=="") is't working put the else is working

Tags: jquery

i can't find what's wrong

[image]

1- a city is working fine

and 2- empty is working fine

3- not a city isn't working id `#not2`

@JS

```
<script>
    $("#find").click(function(event){
        $(".alert").fadeOut();

        event.preventDefault();

        if($("#Wcity").val()!=""){

        $.get("PHP/wS.php?Wcity="+$("#Wcity").val(),function(data){

        if(data==""){
             $("#not2").fadeIn();

         }else{
             $("#FC").html(data).fadeIn();

            };

        });
        }else{
            $("#not").fadeIn()
        }

    });
```

@html

```
    <form>
        <input id="Wcity" type="text" placeholder="Eg. Tokyo , london , Alexandria">
        <input id="find" type="submit" value="Find My City">
    </form>
    <div id="not" class="alert">please enter a city</div>
    <div id="not2" class="alert">Could not find weather data for the city, Try again</div>
    <div id="FC" class="alert"></div>
    <span id="me">created by Nrome ,uses weather-forecast.com</span>
```

hank for your help

Comment: Try using  `===` ,  you may also need to check if `undefined` .

Comment: No difference between `==` and `===` when comparing empty strings, and `$element.val()` return a string.

Comment: try using (!data), this will catch all falsey values like null and undefined as well

Comment: Press F12 in your browser, and go to the Scripts tab.  Put a breakpoint on the line that says "if (data=="")".  Then type in the bogus city name, press the button, and wait for your breakpoint to get hit.  Then you can step through the code and understand exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the problem is that your PHP call is not returning success, so therefore your success function is not even getting called.  You need to specify a "failure function" that gets executed whenever the PHP call fails.

See the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) for how to specify your failure function.

Here's what I would do:

```
$("#find").click(function(event){
    $(".alert").fadeOut();
    event.preventDefault();

    if($("#Wcity").val()!=""){

        $.get("PHP/wS.php?Wcity="+$("#Wcity").val(),function(data){

            if(data.trim()==""){
                 $("#not2").fadeIn();
            }else{
                 $("#FC").html(data).fadeIn();
            };
        })
        .fail(function() {
            $("#not2").fadeIn();
        });
    }else{
        $("#not").fadeIn()
    }
});
```

Comment: How to go that ,that my fourth day with php

Comment: See my updated answer above.  Pay attention to the part where it says ".fail".

Comment: Sorry, my fault.  I made a mistake.  I thought your PHP call was failing, but in fact it is succeeding with a return value that contains a couple of newline characters.  So comparing (data=="") won't work, because the string is not technically empty.  Add a ".trim()" to it, and hopefully it will work now.  See my updated code above that uses "if (data.trim()=="")".

Comment: The Javascript trim method is removing whitespace from beginning and end of the string.  Since your string is coming back from PHP with two newline characters in it, the trim removes those two newlines, and therefore you're left with an empty string.